# How to get the image path when applying UUID to the image file name

Tags: django, django-models

I've implemented a function that applies a UUID-based name to images in my Django project. The function is used as the `upload_to` parameter for the `ImageField` in my `Image` model. Below is the code:

```py
# models.py

def image_file_path(instance, filename):
    """Generate file path for new image"""
    
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    filename = f'{uuid.uuid4()}{ext}'
    return f'{instance.category.name}-{filename}'


class Image(models.Model):
    """Image model"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_file_path,
                              null=False,
                              blank=False)
    results = models.TextField(default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def calculate_results(self):
        from .preprocessing.brain.preprocess_image import get_image_results
        print("Image URL:", self.image) # Returns the original image name
        self.results = get_image_results(self.image.path, target_size=(150, 150))
        return self.results

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category.name}-{self.created_at}"
```

```py
# views.py

@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
class CreateImageView(CreateView):
    model = Image
    form_class = ImageForm
    template_name = 'home.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('upload_homepage')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.calculate_results()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
# templates/home.html

{% if image %}

     <img src="/static/media/{{ image.url }}">

 {% endif %}
```

However, when I am trying to access `image.url` in the `home.html`, I retrieve the original image name upon upload, not the one with the newly generated `UUID`. How can I modify this to obtain the correct name to display in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Try `image.image.url`

You should not need /static/media/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a prefix of `/static/media/` for rendering you image in `templates/home.html`. Since you are uploading the image to `ImageField`, this is not necessary.

What you need is `{{ image.image.url }}` (for rendering full image URL) & `{{ image.image.path }}` (for rendering image file path).

```
# templates/home.html

{% if image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```